# What am I doing wrong storing my Stripe API credentials in credentials.yml.enc?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have my stripe elements working in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4j05Lu6/

which suspects me to believe i am somehow not connecting to their api correctly.

because the payment form itself wont show up.  Here's how it looks for me: http://jsfiddle.net/x2ucpv5y/

^ This is with the API not connected.  The form itself won't appear... and that's what i see on my side in the appp

In my source, this appears:

```
<script src="/assets/stripejs.self-515a5c43d0bc8c4cedc1b733a487b87626dd61e39c6df9c0033b4c3359d4355b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

And that's it for Stripe related and that's my local file.

Here are my fixes attempts:

I have my stripe.rb file structured like this:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:publishable_key],
  :secret_key      => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:secret_key]
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

and then saved my credentials files like this:

```
stripe:   
    publishable_key: 123456789
    secret_key: 123456789
```

I then receive the error when starting my servier:

```
undefined method \credentials' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)`
```

Is there something wrong I'm doing?

Attempt: 2:

I tried doing in the stripe.rb file...

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:publishable_key],
  Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:secret_key]
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

with and withou tthe last time... I get the error: "syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input"

I have also tried filling in the API keys locally like this:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['pk_test_1234567890'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['sk_test_1234567890']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[':secret_key'] #also tried with key in here <<
```

Tried disabling turbo links (saw a post on this) but didn't work.

The keys are correct, they were copied and pasted.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong, something I have that can interfere (such as Dontenv, which i am using for AWS API)

The thing is, shouldn't it be working without the correct API keys anyway since it works in fiddle. in terms of it simply appearing?

View:

```
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="stripejs.js"></script>

    <form id="form-element" action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="card-element">
          Credit or debit card
        </label>
        <div id="card-element">
          <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
        </div>

        <!-- Used to display form errors -->
        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
      </div>

      <button id="button-element">Submit Payment</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: The second JSFiddle that isn't rendering the form is showing the following JS error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined`. Are you sure you are loading stripe properly?

Comment: I don't believe I am but also don't know why... I updated my post to include my view.  How should i be loading stripe?

Comment: Join this chat room and I'll try to help you out: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/182560/rails-stripe-chat?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this with a similar issue...

For me, it was bootstrap causing the problems.  All you need to do is use class="form-control" within the Stripe Elements form for it to display correctly - if you're using Bootstrap.